# Distributed database transactions

Tags: java, database, transactions, distributed-transactions

I am trying to write to 3 different databases: MySQL, Oracle and MongoDB. The requirement is that all 3 databases should be in a consistent state. For e.g if the write to MySQL and Oracle succeeded, and mongo failed(e.g. network failure), then there should be a way to write the failed record back to mongo to keep all 3 records consistent. What's the best way to do this? Should I implement a queue to store failed records and have some background process to read records from the queue and try to write it again to the failed database?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be the [Java Transaction API (JTA)](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/jta_1_2_it_s).    I have not personally used it but it seems to be the Java "industry standard" for distributed transactions.

Comment: User, are you referring to 2 phase commits? The only hitch is I am not sure how to involve mongodb in the whole distributed transaction, as it doesn't really have support for automatic distributed transactions